# How do I install Mysql with Macports

Tags: mysql, macports

I am trying to connect a QT app to an SQL database, however keep getting an error with the qmysql driver not loading. Having spent a week now trying all possible solutions, the final solution was to try and install mysql using macports.

I am using a mac with OS Catalina.

I have installed MacPorts using the recommended pkg file.

I have confirmed installation using *'port version'* with the following response *'Version: 2.6.2'*

As per the instructions on the macports website I try to install using the following command:

*$ sudo port install mysql8-server*

I get the following error:

*Error: Port mysql8-server not found*

I have tried other ports listed on the macports website for mysql and all return the same error. Would greatly appreciate if anyone can point out where I might be going wrong and how to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who experiences this problem, following installation run a self update and refresh all of the ports. For some reason on a new install the ports are not updated.